# How to disable PayPal shipping option with PHP

Tags: php, paypal, sdk, paypal-sandbox

I have created a PayPal sandbox transaction like you see with then code below. It works fine. But now i want to disable the shipping adress dialog at paypal site.
I found this:

```
$inputfields = new \PayPal\Api\InputFields();
$inputfields->getNoShipping(1);
```

But i get it not work. What is still missing?

```
$apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential( PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID, PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET ));

$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency('EUR'); 
$amount->setTotal($price);             
$amount->setDetails($details);

$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount)
    ->setDescription( ... )
    ->setNotifyUrl(  ... );

$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl( ... );
    ->setCancelUrl( ... );      

$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");        

$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent("sale")
    ->setPayer($payer)
    ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
    ->setTransactions(array($transaction));

try {   
    $payment->create($apiContext);
} catch (\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $e) { }
```

Answer (score 4):

It's an old question but i think it's still relevant:

You have to wrap the InputFields in a profile (WebProfile for example).

```
use PayPal\Api\InputFields;
use PayPal\Api\WebProfile;

$inputFields = new \PayPal\Api\InputFields();
$inputFields
   ->setAllowNote(true)
   ->setNoShipping(1)
   ->setAddressOverride(0);

$webProfile = new \PayPal\Api\WebProfile();
$webProfile
   ->setName('testname' . uniqid())
   ->setId("999")
   ->setInputFields($inputFields)
   ->setTemporary(true);
```

Then create the profile and add it to the Payment.

```
$webProfileId = $webProfile->create($apiContext)->getId("999");

$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setExperienceProfileId($webProfileId);
```